# Do the streams in the Process returned by Runtime.exec need to be closed?

Tags: java, exec

I am trying to diagnose a resources leak and want to know if ALL the streams in the Process created by Runtim.exec need to be close.

I have looked through the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) and see no mention that they need to be explicitly closed.

If they do not it would be very helpful.

Comment: Are you really still using Java 7? Here is a more up to date documentation, although it also does not mention the streams should be closed explicitly. But it is mentioned the input streams definitely should be read: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri, no were are using at least java 8 if not latter, depending on the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the streams returned by `Runtime.exec` should be closed to avoid resource leaks.

From the [process docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html)

> The parent process uses these streams to feed input to and get output
> from the subprocess. Because some native platforms only provide
> limited buffer size for standard input and output streams, failure to
> promptly write the input stream or read the output stream of the
> subprocess may cause the subprocess to block, and even deadlock.
>
> The subprocess is not killed when there are no more references to the
> Process object, but rather the subprocess continues executing
> asynchronously.

Comment: @andrewJames I have added reference to oracle docs